# What is happening with my python and terminal on ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I utilize Ubuntu 20.4 and python3.10, but when I run:
`sudo apt-get update or sudo apt update`
my terminal show me this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFou/?nd.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 12, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

When I run: `sudo apt-get upgrade` no problems happen.

Detail my python3.8 and python3.10 run normally

I don't know what is this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. `or sudo apt update`is just not a valid argument for `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem today. I did some search via google. Per https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/errors-trying-to-run-apt-get-update-4175665017/#3, finally my problem is fixed by followings:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
ls -la apt.pkg.*
```

if apt.pkg.so is no there, copy the one to there.

```
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```